# Using 'sed' to find and replace ampersand (&) with problem

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

Special case with ampersand (&) with `sed`

Want to replace string with `&` character string in `bash`

```
INPUT: 

var1=''XXX&XXX'
Input : sed -i 's/WW/$var1/g' test

Output:

$cat test
XXXWWXXX
```

expected output would be : `XXX&XXX`

PS: String would by Dynamic, So here i don't want to modify variable with escape character, Any solution in
Shell ?

Comment: Escape `&` which is special meta character in `sed`. So use: `sed -i 's/WW/XXX\&XXX/g' test`

Comment: I just updated my question @anubhava

Comment: Yes, it's work but after modify variable, that I don't want to do @anubhava

Comment: slash (`/`) isn't an escape character, backslash (```\```) is.

Comment: If your input is `XXXWWXXX` and you want to replace `WW` with `XXX&XXX` then the expected output should not be `XXX&XXX` it should be `XXXXXX&XXXXXX`.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
var1='XXX&XXX'

# Use double quotes in sed
# Note: & is escaped
sed "s/WW/${var1//&/\\&}/g" <<< '123 WW foo WW xyz.'
```

**Output:**

```
123 XXX&XXX foo XXX&XXX xyz.
```

Comment: It will work But string would anything in anytime (It's a dynamic), So its not good idea to modify variable everytime.

Comment: If you can see in first posted question where already mentioned that `here i don't want to modify variable with / character(slash), Any solution in Shell ?` may available in history. Thanks for you support...Keep help to community :) If you think, I posted answer is helpful for Users then verify/Accept it.

Comment: I believe you mistyped `/` in your question and Ed commented same that `/` is not used for escaping but \ is

Answer (score 1):

Since you said `i don't want to modify variable with / (sic) escape character` - this will use literal string matches for both the existing text you want to match (`WW`) and its replacement (`XXX&XXX`) which is how you avoid escaping any chars in either of them:

```
var1='XXX&XXX'
old='WW' new="$var1" awk '
    BEGIN {
        old = ENVIRON["old"]
        new = ENVIRON["new"]
        lgth = length(old)
    }
    {
        head = ""
        tail = $0
        while ( s = index(tail,old) ) {
            head = head substr(tail,1,s-1) new
            tail = substr(tail,s+lgth)
        }
        $0 = head tail
        print
    }
' test
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for how I'm using the shell and awk variables.

You can't do the above with sed since sed doesn't understand literal strings so if you want to use sed then see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Comment: Consider, Here String would be dynamic, So how can deal with `&` character.

Comment: There are no Here Strings in your question so idk for sure what you're referring to. If it's just that the file `test` can be a Here String instead of a file then simply replace `test` with `<<< 'XXXWWXXX'`. Not sure why you had to ask about that - is there more to your question than that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution is that, In a recent shell this could be done like,

Need to put this `//&/\\&` static set of character to solve this ampersand (&) problem with `sed`

```
s1="XXX&XXX"

sed "s/ww/${s1//&/\\&}/g" <<< 'this is ww'

this is XXX&XXX
```

Other situation,

```
s2="&xx&xx&x&"

sed "s/ww/${s2//&/\\&}/g" <<< 'this is ww'

this is &xx&xx&x&
```

*A quick search revealed the culprit;*

```
The REPLACEMENT can contain \N (N being a number from 1 to 9, inclusive) 
references, which refer to the portion of the match which is contained 
between the Nth \( and its matching \). Also, the REPLACEMENT can contain 
unescaped & characters which reference the whole matched portion of the pattern space
```

Let’s try with **awk**

```
URI='https://user:pass@example.com/?num=42&type=magic'
$ echo 'my_link = %link%' | awk "{ gsub(/%link%/, \"$URI\"); print }"
my_link = https://user:pass@example.com/?num=42%link%type=magic
```

Find more detail on https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Cheers!

Comment: You specifically said `i don't want to modify variable with / (sic) escape character` and here you are posting an answer that modifies the variable with an escape character. You're having to use double escapes and escape quotes because you're using double instead of single quotes around your scripts btw - don't do that and your programs will become simpler. Also, and importantly, note that `&` isn't the only character that'd need escaping it it appeared in `s1` - there are several.